# I keep getting [object HTMLTextAreaElement] as a response from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea

I can't figure out what the issue is. Even the already existing question about this doesn't help.

`document.getElementById("output").value = codeDecoded`

The HTML is:

```
<h3>Input</h3>
<textarea placeholder="Input..." id="input"></textarea>
<h3>Output</h3>
<textarea id="output" placeholder="Output..." readonly></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="decode(document.getElementById('input'))" class="btn btn-primary">Decode</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById("input") returns the `<textarea>` element itself, rather than its value. To receive the actual text, you need onclick="decode(document.getElementById('input')**.value**)"